# Invalid object name dbo.MenuItems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I developed a site using asp.net mvc 3 and used ef code first to generate the database. the scaffolding works fine on my local machine using the built in sql compact database. Then i used one click web deploy to a hosting company and i started getting the error below. If you have encountered this problem before please advice.

```
    [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.MenuItems'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean    breakConnection) +404
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +412
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +1363
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +118
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +6387873
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +6389442
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +538
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +28
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +256
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +19
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +553

[EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +10646103
   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +11488485
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +11120473
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +47
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +382
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
   Bonappetit.Controllers.MenuItemsController.Index() in c:\Bonappetit\Bonappetit\Controllers\MenuItemsController.cs:21
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +264
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +129
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +826266
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +314
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +825488
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +335
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +54
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is trying to access an object which does not exist

Possible reasons

1) your table is not created /avaiable in the server

2) your not connected to the correct database.

Check these two and you will be in a good shape to proceed further.

Comment: i am sure i am connected to the correct database, so it must be option (1) .. the database on the host server is empty even after i do the deployment .. i configured the publishing settings to copy data and schema from my local database to the host database .. however when i checked the host database it is still completely empty .. am i supposed to migrate the schema manually to host database? .. what would be the point of one click web deploying then!